# How do I play sound file in a C++ node with sound_play

Tags: ros, audio-common, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone. I want to play a sound file on a C++ node with sound_play. I have downloaded the audio_common package already , but I don't know how to use it to realize my purpose.
Please anyone can give me a detailed tutorial .
I use indigo catkin ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233956/how-do-i-play-sound-file-in-a-c++-node-with-sound_play/) by [Joy.Lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26415/joy.lin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the 'Code API' link on the [sound_play wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/sound_play) you can get to the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/latest-available/api/sound_play/html/classsound__play_1_1SoundClient.html) and [example](http://docs.ros.org/latest-available/api/sound_play/html/test_8cpp_source.html) for the C++ SoundPlay client.

The function you probably want to use is `playWaveFromPkg`; it should look something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "example");

    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    sound_play::SoundClient sc;

    sc.playWaveFromPkg("sound_play", "sounds/BACKINGUP.ogg");

    ros::spin();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joy.Lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26415/joy.lin/) on 2016-05-14**:
Thank you very much . I can play the sound file successfully!!
However, I can't control its volume, it's always too low.

**Comment by [rodrigobdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/27135/rodrigobdz/) on 2016-06-11**:
The documentation and example links are broken

**Comment by [rodrigobdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/27135/rodrigobdz/) on 2016-06-11**:
The links are now found under the docs directory for each distribution

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-11**:
Fixed the links; thanks for catching that.